# Jenkins not able to find an artifact

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have 3 components in my project.

```
1) Services. (the core part)
2) Webservice. (Uses component 1)
3) JOBs. (Uses component 1)
```

I am using Jenkins for CI and Maven as a build tool.
Component 2(Webservice) builds fine. But Component 3(JOBs) throws an error which is as follows

```
Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version: 2.4.4
Artifactory integration is disabled
[CFT-JOBS-BRANCH-BUILD] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK-1.7.79/bin/java -classpath /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven-3.3.9/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar -Dmaven.home=/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven-3.3.9 -Dclassworlds.conf=/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven-3.3.9/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CFT-JOBS-BRANCH-BUILD/CPIIJOBS-branch org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -f CPIIJOBS-branch/pom.xml -B clean deploy -Dmaven.repo.local=/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/tag-repository -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DrepositoryId=releases -Dpackaging=tar.gz -DaltDeploymentRepository=releases::default::http://10.10.200.125:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for net.nationalpayment.cp20.scheduler:scheduler:war:4.32.0.versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 109, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building cp20 Scheduler Spring-Quartz Application 4.32.0.versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://10.10.200.125:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/net/nationalpayment/cp20/services/4.32.0.versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://10.10.200.125:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/net/nationalpayment/cp20/services/4.32.0.versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT/services-4.32.0.versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] The POM for net.nationalpayment.cp20:services:jar:4.32.0.versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: http://10.10.200.125:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/net/nationalpayment/cp20/services/4.32.0.versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT/services-4.32.0.versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.526 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-26T05:31:55+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project scheduler: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.nationalpayment.cp20.scheduler:scheduler:war:4.32.0.versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact net.nationalpayment.cp20:services:jar:4.32.0.versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT in XYZ (http://10.10.200.125:8081/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
```

Below is the entry in the pom.xml for component 2 and 3 for inclusion of component 1.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.nationalpayment.cp20</groupId>
        <artifactId>services</artifactId>
        <version>${current.build.version}</version>
    </dependency>


</properties>
<current.build.version>versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT</current.build.version>
</properties>
```

This property is updated by >com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin

Why is it not finding the jar file for Component 3 whereas, it is working fine for component 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you should Change to a multi-module build

Comment: Thanks for your time Jens But how will it help. And why is not discoverable in current mode of building as a plugin.